# CSS background-image in IMG elements not displaying in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, background-image, image

I have an IMG tag with an background-image property. Whilst both images display in FF, only the IMG src image displays in IE. At this stage I am not concerned with positioning or anything, I just want both IMG src and background-image displayed on the page.

Here is my basic test HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>carmen's test page </title>
    <style>
        .icon {
            display: block;
            background-image: url('drop-yes.gif');
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            padding: 200px 200px 200px 200px;
            margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
        } 
    </style>
</head>
<body>    

<div> <img class="icon" src="drop-no.gif"/> </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Which version(s) of IE? IE5/Mac doesn't support CSS urls delimited by single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe your Doctype is a problem

#### [Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/NKpPW/)

in this test it works fine in IE with:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title> Page Title </title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
.icon {
   display: block;
   background: url(http://dummyimage.com/450x450/dad/fff&text=yes) no-repeat;
   padding: 200px 200px 200px 200px;
   margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
} 
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div> <img class="icon" src="http://dummyimage.com/50x50/444/fff&text=no"/> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is a disturbingly specific doctype for a superseded specification. Use `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">` instead.

Comment: it's the one that my ancient editor defaults too.. thank you for reminder (upsated answer too)! though I think what I meant was to say any Strict rendering Doctype will do ;) scuttles off to update my editor :)

Comment: Awesome! The doctype it was (or more precisesly, it wasn't) Thank you.

Comment: Make sure you accept @clairesuzy's answer, @Carmen. Thanks, @clairesuzy, you solved a problem that's been plaguing me.

Comment: @Rob Heiser You're Welcome, glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't suggest giving the `<img>` css class background **and** a `src`; rather place it in a `<div>` instead and manipulate that as you need.  You should get a result like this: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p8UCK/16/)